# bootstrap css text not vertical align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a horizontal counter to mark the step you are currently working on. We use bootstrap 4. The css works without the bootstrap but when I add it into the project it's not aligning vertical. The text is bellow the circle.

[image]

The number should be centred both vertical and horizontal inside the circle.

How do I make this css work in the bootstrap project?

**HTML**

```css
.steps {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.steps div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.steps .circle {
  border-radius:100px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  line-height: 75px;
}

.steps .separator {
  width: 100px;
  margin:0px -5px 0px -5px;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.steps .done {
 color:#35FF8B;
}

.steps .done .circle {
 border:3px solid #35FF8B;
 background:#385463;
}

.steps .done .separator {
 border:4px solid #35FF8B;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div class="done">
    <div class="circle">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this using line-height also... remove the padding and add `width:75px` and `height: 75px;` and `line-height:75px`;

```css
.steps {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.steps div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.steps .circle {
  border-radius:100px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  line-height: 75px;
}

.steps .separator {
  width: 100px;
  margin:0px -5px 0px -5px;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.steps .done {
  color:#35FF8B;
}

.steps .done .circle {
  border:3px solid #35FF8B;
  background:#385463;
}

.steps .done .separator {
  border:4px solid #35FF8B;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div class="done">
    <div class="circle">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked :D Just have one detail still not working for me. The number is not vertical aligned.

See updated picture in post :)

Comment: Glad to helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the final layout should look like, but I would use flexboxes to center both horizontally and vertically.

```css
.steps {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.steps .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: thin solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.steps .separator {
  width: 100px;
}

.steps .done {
 color:#35FF8B;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.steps .done .circle {
 border:3px solid #35FF8B;
 background:#385463;
}

.steps .done .separator {
 border:4px solid #35FF8B;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div class="done">
    <div class="circle">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for bootstrap alignments

```
<span class="align-baseline">baseline</span>
<span class="align-top">top</span>
<span class="align-middle">middle</span>
<span class="align-bottom">bottom</span>
<span class="align-text-top">text-top</span>
<span class="align-text-bottom">text-bottom</span>
```

Refer the documentation [Vertical-Alignments-Demo](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/)